# Mobile user agent check

Tags: regex, mobile

I've been using the following user agent Regular Expression to detect mobile devices, but I recently came across a few resources that listed a whole host of mobile user agents that I had not heard of before.

Whilst my agent check is only the first step in the detection process - I also have some JavaScript as a fallback - I would like for it to contain the majority of *currently* undisputed mobile "keywords" so as to optimise the user experience for those handsets. I would also like to keep things as future-proof as possible, but this can only ever be argued with good reasoning and not *set-in-stone*.

The core of the regexp follows - please note the user agent string has had it's white-space removed. The check is also specifically case dependent.

*Please ignore the newlines; they are for formatting only.*

```
/i[Pp]hone|[Mm]obile[Ss]afari|[Ww]indowsCE|[Ww]indows[Pp]hone|
 IE[Mm]obile|[Oo]pera[Mm]ini|[Oo]pera[Mm]obi|[Bb]lack[Bb]erry|
 [^A-Z]RIM[^A-Z]|[Ss]ony[Ee]ricsson|[Nn]okia|[^A-Z]MIB[^A-Z]/
```

These are the extra edge-case agents that I've found out about:

```
/[Ss]kyfire|[Tt]ea[Ss]hark|[Nn]et[Ff]ront|[Mm]inimo|
 [Ii]ris|[Ff]ennec|[Dd]oris|[Ss]eries60|BOLT|[Bb]lazer/
```

Does anyone have any further suggestions, or possible keywords to remove, that could cause false positives?

For example, I do not include Samsung or Android for the precise reasons that they are not unique to mobile agents. I'd rather let agents through to the JavaScript that I'm unsure about.

As a second note, many user-agents report as *Like Something* - i.e. *Like Mobile Safari* - should I filter these out of the equation, or if something is reporting this; is it also likely to be a mobile device.

Comment: It is better to detect *features* than devices, for example using [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to cater for small screens, or [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to handle touch events. The most important question is WHY you want to detect a mobile user. What will you do differently for them?

Comment: Take a look at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com. You can download scripts in almost any language, including PHP, and take a look at the regex voodoo. Also be sure to provide a link to the non-mobile version so that the user can choose to go to the full site should they choose to do that or if the detection fails.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, however their regex voodoo - whilst seemingly rather inclusive - is also rather cryptic. I would have a hard time justifying the reasons behind each particular check to the server team I'm working alongside. Although looking at the regexp has raised a good point because I have no idea what my client expects to happen with Kindle devices ;)

Comment: The site I linked uses the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) database. You can download the database, pick and choose which user agents you want to support. You will have to do all the regex voodoo yourself though.

Comment: Yeah, I recently came across WURFL and also read about their new license preventing people from breaking it up and using it in an unlicensed way. Whilst I could probably do such a thing and not be found out, I don't agree with ignoring licenses and would rather develop my own solution. It is a useful link however to others who may find this.

Comment: Any reason not to use a case-insensitive flag to avoid all the `[Aa]` character classes? Additionally, it would seem to me that you could simply surround the branching in `\b` word-boundary "characters", or put the `[^a-z]` classes there. E.g. `/\b(iphone|mobile| ... |nokia|mib)\b/i`

Answer (score 2):

First of all I guess your first step of the detection process is processed **server side** because you said there is a fallback which is processed by JavaScript.
Therefore I guess you only perform a **HTTP User-Agent** check so far.

### Suggestion BlackBerry

I would recommend to add also a check of the [Accept request header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to your first step of detection.

In one of my recent projects I ran into trouble cause the HTTP User-Agent detection of **BlackBerry** failed in some cases. For these casees I had to add an Accept request header check which looks for `/vnd.rim/`.
I didn't find out much about the background why it happens. I only know some BlackBerry browsers try to emulate IE or Firefox.

#### Example

Taken from the [BlackBerry 8120 device specification document](http://www.blackberry.net/go/mobile/profiles/uaprof/8120/4.3.0.rdf): `application/vnd.rim.html`

### Suggestion J2ME Devices

Clients using this technology might be quite rare but to be sure you could include another RegEx for `midp` to cover all kind of MIDP devices.

### Question

I know they're dead but I think there are still some around. What about Palm and webOS devices?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the good points, and pointing out that I had totally missed to state server side, my bad :) you are correct in your assumptions. I had not considered the `Accept request header` at all, I shall do some research...